# Ambiguous comportement from spring data with projectors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

Any one can help me ?  I 'm so ambiguous with spring data So the example is
I have address entity

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
}
```

projector interface

```
public interface AddressView {
    String getZipCode();
}
```

and the repository

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<Address, Long> {
    List<AddressView> getAddressByState(String state);
    List<AddressView> findAll();
```

test

```
List<AddressView> addressViewList = addressRepository.getAddressByState("test");
        List<AddressView> addressViewList2 = addressRepository.findAll();
```

the first request getAddressByState work fine and return the addresses
but the second one findall I have that issue
**No converter found capable of converting from type .......**

is that normal ?
Thnak you!

Answer (score 0):

you are defining **Address** as an expected response in the **AddressRepository**

By calling **getAddressByState()** AND **findAll()** you will get Adress and not AddressView,
think of using DTO

Comment: NO when I call getAddressByState I get AddressView